# How to change my old url to the new one?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, seo, product-urls

How can I change my **old Url** into new one for **SEO betterment**?

Under I have given the screen shot of my old product url.[image]

Now How can I change this product url to- "http://example.com/fastrack-watch-3110sm03-in-bangladesh"

I am looking for the answer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you need to set from the backend whether you want product urls with categgory or not

Exactly from backend Go to Admin - catalog - catalog - Search engine optimization - Use Categories Path for Product URLs select as (NO) for product url

This will fix your concern

Comment: is that what you tried to search?